# C# Trick with lambdas

Tags: c#, lambda

There is some code, but the thing is very simple. I want to pass a function as a parameter, but the function is so short that it could've been created by lambda.

```
    class Hidden
    {
        public List<string> GetData()
        {
            return new List<string>();
        }
    }

    class Main
    {
        Dictionary<int, Hidden> dir = new Dictionary<int, Hidden>();

        public Main()
        {
            Friend f = new Friend(MethodToBeReplacedByLambda);
        }

        public List<string> MethodToBeReplacedByLambda(int id)
        {
            return dir[id].GetData();
        }
    }

    class Friend
    {
        public Friend(Func<int, List<string>> GetData)
        {
            List<string> result = GetData(4);
        }
    }
```

I want to delete this method

```
    public List<string> MethodToBeReplacedByLambda(int id)
    {
        return dir[id].GetData();
    }
```

And be able to pass this as a parameter by lambda. Any ideas? :D

**UPDATE:** I've tried:

```
Friend f = new Friend((int, List<string>) => dir[id].GetData());
```

Comment: This is pretty simple, so it would be nice to know exactly what is confusing you.

Comment: I tried this: Friend f = new Friend((int, List<string>) => dir[id].GetData());

Comment: You're not supposed to put the type names on the left hand side of the lambda. The compiler can figure that out from the constructor header of Friend.

Comment: I am confused by the structure… I don't know how to create it on the fly

Comment: You just put a comma delimited list of your param names on the left (inside parentheses if there is more than one), and then "=>", and then your code, which needs to be inside curly braces and have semicolons if there is more than one statement.

Comment: For lambdas, you don't put the return type in the parenthesis, just the arguments. The compiler will figure out the return type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Friend f = new Friend((id) => dir[id].GetData());
```

Comment: Thanks! Since you were first I will mark your answer as the one that solved the problem when 15 will pass :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a lambda that uses the int value from the function:

```
Friend f = new Friend(id => dir[id].GetData())
```

Only the parameter names (that you use) need to be passed to the lambda, and not the return value of `GetData`. If you have multiple parameters, wrap them in parenthesis.